# Anime, fighters dueling in the style of their spirit animals

Tags: story-identification, anime

Guys I am trying to find I watched as a child. About 8 years ago it was airing on Bulgaria television but the show itself could be much older. I don't remember much about except it was most awesome thing I have ever seen and the following details:

- The animation was well done a little bit dark but it was suitable for
  children. I don't remember any modern urban settings(subways,malls)
  in the episodes. Most of the stories were in temples, graveyards,
  traditional Japanese houses or fields. However I do believe that the timeline of the
  story was going on in the late 1990s or early 2000s
- The main characters were teenagers, each one of them had a spiritual guardian or something like this. The spirit could be anything like dragon, gorilla. The fighting style and choice of weapon was inspired by the spirit guardian. I can't remember if the spirits were participating in the fights directly, I think not. As far as I remember the characters were channeling their powers or something.
- The fights were in a duel style, where you wait for your opponent to perform his move and then you perform yours. The characters were executing the sweet moves by shouting the name of the sweet move beforehand. For example I recall one of the characters jumping in the air and shouting "SKY SLASH" and then executing something awesome. *Note it might not be *sky slash* in English as I was watching in dubbed Bulgarian

Comment: Sky Slash is a move seen in Dragon Quest; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Quest:_Dai_no_Daib%C5%8Dken

Comment: Thanks but it is not that one.

Comment: the dragonquest manga was good, but doesn't have any spirit guardians involved, but i immediately thought of that as well when i read sky slash.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Familiar

Comment: You honestly just described, in great detail, about 4200 anime shows. lol

Comment: It is the Shaman King. Many thanks to  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/7302/dungarth !

Comment: @user35675 Don't forget to **accept** Dungarth's answer (click on the little checkmark below the voting buttons) to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 11):

Could it be [Shaman King](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaman_King)?

Its a show about shamanistic warriors engaged in some sort of tournament that occurs every 500 years with the purpose of crowning the Shaman King. To do battle, a shaman summons a guardian spirit, usually the spirit of a long dead warrior, an elemental spirit or even the spirits of mythical beasts (even some skeletons during a cemetary fight, apparently).

The show originally ran in Japan from 1998 to 2004 and was widely popular, so it's not at all impossible that it aired in Bulgaria 10 years or so ago.

[Here's one of the english intros](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qLl145FqQg), maybe you can recognize some of the characters?

Comment: Always a pleasure! Don't forget to officially accept the answer if you find it satisfactory ^_^